# What is the correct way to rename a mount point?

Tags: partitioning

I have the following partitions in Ubuntu

[image]

I want to rename `/media/mario/Files1` to `/media/mario/Files`

What is the correct way to rename a mount point?

**Update 0**

When I go up from `/media/mario/Files1/` to `/media/mario/` I notice there is already a point called Files. Attached image

[image]

Could I rename it?

**Update 1**

This is the output of `mount`

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8025280k,nr_inodes=2006320,mode=755,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1612696k,mode=755,inode64)
/dev/nvme0n1p5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=23575)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/bare_5.snap on /snap/bare/5 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_16202.snap on /snap/core/16202 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_16574.snap on /snap/core/16574 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2796.snap on /snap/core18/2796 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2812.snap on /snap/core18/2812 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_2105.snap on /snap/core20/2105 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_2182.snap on /snap/core20/2182 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_1033.snap on /snap/core22/1033 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_1122.snap on /snap/core22/1122 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_3836.snap on /snap/firefox/3836 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_3941.snap on /snap/firefox/3941 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_194.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/194 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_198.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-38-2004_140.snap on /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-38-2004_143.snap on /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_132.snap on /snap/gnome-42-2204/132 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_141.snap on /snap/gnome-42-2204/141 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk2-common-themes_13.snap on /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1534.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1535.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004_2.snap on /snap/hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004/2 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/mcomix-tabetai_7.snap on /snap/mcomix-tabetai/7 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_1113.snap on /snap/snap-store/1113 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_959.snap on /snap/snap-store/959 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_20671.snap on /snap/snapd/20671 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_21184.snap on /snap/snapd/21184 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd-desktop-integration_57.snap on /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/57 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd-desktop-integration_83.snap on /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/nvme0n1p5 on /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell type ext4 (ro,noexec,noatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1612696k,mode=755,inode64)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/snapd-desktop-integration.mnt type nsfs (rw)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1612692k,nr_inodes=403173,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/snap-store.mnt type nsfs (rw)
/dev/nvme0n1p3 on /media/mario/Files1 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/firefox.mnt type nsfs (rw)
```

Comment: what is the existing "Files" directory for? are you the only user of this system? it would help if you showed us the output of `mount`. please add it to your question

Comment: Yes, I am the only user. The need for this change is that now suddenly the drive `/media/mario/Files` changed to `/media/mario/Files1`

Comment: Could I just delete this `Files` directory and rename `Files1` to `Files`? Is this safe?

Comment: For a general method see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40118578/165358). If you can see that `Files1` does contain all your data, I suggest to copy the data elsewhere to be safe before deleting `Files`.

Comment: "Could I just delete this Files directory and rename Files1 to Files? Is this safe?" that is why i asked you to provide the output of the mount command. that will help us tell if it is safe to delete the Files directory (eg if there isn't another volume mounted to it, it should be safe to delete). alternately, you could move the Files dir out of the way with `sudo mv /media/mario/Files /media/mario/FilesOLD`. if somthing is mounted to Files, it won't let you. if successful, then you can proceed to rename Files1 to Files, and reconfigure your mount parameters.

Comment: I update the question adding the output of `mount`

Comment: ok, looks like Files is not in use. just to be safe though, try renaming Files to something else. then you can unmount your Files1 volume, and try renaming Files1 to Files. How did you establish the mountpoint for the disk in the first place? since you said you didnt see it in fstab, that hints that you  used some users-pace method for mounting the disk.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Frank. Your advice helped me solve it. Renaming `Files` helped me solve it. The behavior of changing `Files` to `Files1` occurred when adding a new hard drive, for some unknown reason this caused the name change. Temporarily removing the HD fixed the problem. The reason for rescuing this name `Files` is that a docker volume was created in it and since it was not available it did not allow me to run the container that occupies this volume